# How autoCommit works and how many message will be polled once in spring-cloud-stream reactive kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, reactor, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I check the [document](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/index.html), it only says how auto commit works with `poll()` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-consumer-properties), and how to configure poll count, [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/3.0.10.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_polling_configuration_properties).

So how things works when I use `Flux`?

Below are my consumer code.

```
    @Bean
    fun consumerInboundMsg(handler: QueueHandler): java.util.function.Function<Flux<MessageRequest>, Mono<Void>> {
        return Function { flux ->
            flux.asFlow().flatMapMerge {
                flow {
                    handler.handleInboundRequest(it)
                    emit(it)
                }
            }.asFlux().then()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify, the auto commit mechanism is determined by the Apache Kafka's implementation. You're using Spring Cloud Stream reactive or Spring Cloud Stream non-reactive doesn't impact how the auto commit works. The offset will be committed in every poll and check the time elapsed is greater than `auto.commit.interval.ms`.

In case the commit interval is 5 seconds and poll is happening in 7 seconds, the commit will happen after 7 seconds only.

To check how often your consumer commits the offsets, enabling the trace log: `logging.level.org.apache.kafka: trace`